What does (צִיּוֹן) "Zion" mean?
2 Samuel 5:7

7 Nevertheless, David took the stronghold of Zion, that is, the city
of David.


I've gotten some conflicting information:

The word Zion occurs over 150 times in the Bible. It essentially
means “fortification” and has the idea of being “raised up” as a
“monument.” [1]


“Zion” (צִיּוֹן, pronounced “Tziyon”) means “a sign” or “a landmark.” [2]


The Hebrew word for Zion, Tzion (ציון), can be translated as
“indication” or “marking.” [3]

I'm most curious to know what brought them to conclude these meanings of Zion. Such as:
What historical, linguistic, or hermenutical evidence supports the interpretation of Zion as a "fortification"?
How do different scholars or sources conclude that Zion means "a sign" or "a landmark" based on the Hebrew language?
What leads to the understanding of Zion as "indication" or "marking"?
What are the main points of scholarly debate regarding the meaning of Zion?

Here is some usage of the word Zion - https://biblehub.com/hebrew/6726.htm  The word 'Zion' makes for a studious research project.

These are perfect examples of etymological over-reach by overly enthusiastic writers with over-active imaginations.  Zion is simply a proper name that does not necessarily have to have a meaning other than a place-name.  (Many place and personal names did have meanings but NOT all in Hebrew.)

In biblical usage, "Zion" most frequently refers either to Jerusalem or the specific hill on which temple stood. In the NT is can also refer to the spiritual Jerusalem, a Christian concept introduced in the Book of Revelation. See also Hebrews 12:22.
Here are answers to the OP's specific related questions:
Zion as fortification
2 Samuel

7 David captured the fortress of Zion... 9 David then took up
residence in the fortress and called it the City of David.

Psalm 48:12-13

12 Walk about Zion, go around her,
count her towers, 13 consider well her ramparts,
view her citadels, that you may tell of them
to the next generation.

Zion as a sign or landmark
This has to do with the word's etymological root. According to this site 'Zion (צִיּוֹן, pronounced “Tziyon”) means “a sign” or “a landmark.” The root צ-י-ן forms a verb in modern Hebrew today that means “to point out.”'
Zion as a marking
Rabbinical sources understand that this relates to the idea that Israel's people were "marked" spiritually as belonging to God. The Lubavitcher Rebbe taught that the Jewish people are called Tzion by virtue of their study of Jewish texts and fulfillment of G‑d’s commandments.
Scholarly debates
Regarding scholarly debates, most disagreements seem to revolve around whether the fortress was named for the mountain or the word "zion" always meant fortress. There may be other debates as well. Possibly the OP will inform us about them.

"raised up", "monument", "sign", "landmark", "indication", and "marking" all have similar meanings.
It's only "fortification" that doesn't have a directly related meaning.
Zion is sometimes explicitly referred to as a fortification, such as:

2 Samuel 5:7 Nevertheless David took the strong hold of Zion: the same is the city of David.
1 Chronicles 11:5 … Nevertheless David took the castle of Zion, which is the city of David.

In each case though, "Zion" is used as a place name and the "fortification" meaning is contained in the words that describe it.
And even then, the "stronghold" and the "castle" are referring to a fortress built by the Jebusites, at Zion.
"Zion" is correctly referred to as raised up, a monument, a sign, a landmark, an indication, and a marking, because the location itself, the Temple Mount, is a symbol of such great importance to Israel.
There is no justification for thinking that the word itself means "fortification" in Hebrew.
(One should not consider the "Got Questions" site as authoritative on this or any other matter.)
According to Gesenius's Hebrew-Chaldee Lexicon
"Zion" means:

a “sunny place,” a “sunny mountain;” from the root צָהָה
[in Thes. from צָיָה]

Though it also mentions that there is a similar Arabic word that does mean "fortress".

That's wild. A "sunny place" is very different from the other translations. Thanks for the answer! +1
